# How would I obtain a list of column names in a Dataset?

Tags: programming, dataset

I really love the addition of Dataset to Mathematica. I would like to write a basic utility function that exports a Dataset to Excel.

Is there a way to get a list of column names from a Dataset?

Comment: For a flat dataset `Keys` acting on the first row should work.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Could you please explain what you mean by a `flat` Dataset?  Do you mean one where the keys are just primitive types?

Comment: @Shredderroy just a rectangular row x column type of dataset, not one of the fancier types that have embedded structures and such. Basically the first category shown under the Applications heading in the documentation.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, even a "flat" row x column dataset can have embedded structures. Dataset doesn't preclude eg, Graphics in some or all cells. Of course, that wouldn't really use Dataset lookup. Nested Associations allow use of `Query`.

Answer (score 6):

Just an example:

```
tab = Table[{If[PrimeQ[i], "type" -> "Prime", "type" -> "NoPrime"], 
"n" -> i, "dc" -> DigitCount[i!, 2, 1], 
"dc1" -> DigitCount[i! + 1, 2, 1]}, {i, 20, 40}];
```

make a Dataset:

```
ds = Dataset[Association @@@ tab]
```

get the column heads:

```
First@Keys@ds
```

You can then make a table, export, to Excel, or whatever. Excel Export of the values can be done e.g. with

```
temp = Normal@ds[All, {"type", "n", "dc"}] // Values
```

and

```
Export["test.xls", temp]
```

If necessary you can Prepend the column heads to get them into Excel, too.

Comment: mgamer - thank you most kindly!  I will give this a shot.

Comment: For performance purposes I think it is better to use `Keys@First@ds`.

Comment: @AntonAntonov: Absolutely right :-)